# How to change color of Rect within an image if it contains a certain value

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have several ROIs on my image. For each ROI, if it contains a black pixel, I want to color the whole ROI black. Here is my code so far:

```
 int j = 0;
        // this loop sets the ROI rows
        while (j < 10) {
            // this loop sets the ROI columns
            for (int i=0; i<width-1; i+=mini_box_width){
                if (width-i >= mini_box_width){
                // define the Rect, i iterating horizontally
                Rect minibox = Rect(x+i, y, mini_box_height, mini_box_width);

                // Mat minibox_image = frameRGB(minibox);
                // Mat dst;
                // inRange(minibox_image, Scalar(255,255,255), Scalar(255,255,255), dst);

                // plot ROIs
                rectangle(frameRGB, minibox, GREEN);
                // save minibox Rect values in vector
                miniROIs.push_back(minibox);
                }
            }   
        // iterate vertically
        y += mini_box_height;
        j++;
        }
```

I imagine it has something to do with the inRange function, which can make a mask if the image is in the bounds I specified, but how do I apply this to the pixels in the ROIs on the original image?

For example, see this image:

[image]

The image is split into several ROIs. For each ROI in the image, if a black pixel is found, I want to black out all pixels in that ROI on the original image. It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select a region of your image with your `Rect minibox` by *calling* your image with the rectangle: i.e. `region = frameRGB(minibox)`, see the [docs for `Mat::operator()(const Rect& roi)`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4272fce43d7405603fbb5e5f52580e57)

Then you can check if there's a black pixel inside your region with `cv::countNonZero(region == cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0))` ([docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa4b89393263bb4d604e0fe5986723914)). If there's a black pixel you can set all pixels in the region to black simply by assigning zero, like `roi = 0`.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the countNonZero function, that is helpful. However, how do I overlay the set-to-back ROI on the original image?

Comment: @connor449 I think the assignment to the roi is sufficient. When you take a region, you're not creating a copy of the values, just getting a new header to the data, so assignments should mutate the original.